# Python - Tor Browser through Firefox, unable to click button

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have been trying to access a certain site (dumpert.nl) through Tor Browser as proxy via Firefox. The reason I am using Tor Browser is so I can enter the website with a different IP address every time I enter the website. I know this is possible but I have not yet found the way to do this. I have found multiple ways to do this, but they have not (yet) worked for me. Help is wanted on this part as well.

The real problem is I am having trouble with the Accept Cookie page of this website. When I manually click the button to accept the cookies nothing happens. I can't progress to the next page. If i use the .click() function of Selenium nothing happens either, the page is fully loaded so this is not the issue. The buttons do not work for some reason and I have no clue why. I don't know if it's an Tor problem or using Firefox via Tor problem.

I use the following code to navigate to the website:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
    import os
    
    torexe = os.popen(r'C:\Users\nick\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe')
    profile = FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\nick\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default')
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
    profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
    profile.update_preferences()
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile= profile, executable_path=r'C:\Webdrivers\geckodriver.exe')
    driver.get("http://dumpert.nl")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/a").click() #cookie click

    #Rest of my code doing stuff not important for this issue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open the webpage `http://dumpert.nl` and `click()` on the desired button you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
  import os

  torexe = os.popen(r'C:\Users\Soma Bhattacharjee\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe')
  profile = FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\Soma Bhattacharjee\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default')
  profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
  profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
  profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
  profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
  profile.update_preferences()
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile= profile, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://dumpert.nl")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.approve-btn[title^='And yes']>span"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
  import os

  torexe = os.popen(r'C:\Users\Soma Bhattacharjee\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe')
  profile = FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\Soma Bhattacharjee\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default')
  profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
  profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
  profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
  profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
  profile.update_preferences()
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile= profile, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://dumpert.nl")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='approve-btn']/span[starts-with(., 'Yes')]"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: tor_page]

Comment: It's running the code and ends the code without any errors. Yet the code is unable to actually progress to the next screen. If I try to manually click the cookie accept button nothing happens either. It's like I am unable to click at all. The page is fully loaded at this point. Could this be a option that's wrong in my Tor browser?

Comment: @Grasmat If _... manually click the cookie accept button nothing happens either..._ possibly the issue is with your TOR browser/installation. The program executes fine at my end.

Comment: Must be, reinstalling Tor Browser and Firefox has not done the trick. And so the search continues. Anyway thanks for your help so far

Answer (score 0):

There is an option, I think in the privacy tab, where you can turn off javascript.

For me it sounds like you switched it off, because many buttons still work with  JS.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).