# How to bypass Tor Network Settings confirmation popup using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, tor, firefox-profile

I'm attempting to automate the use of the Tor browser through selenium:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
binary = '/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox'
firefox_binary = FirefoxBinary(binary)
try:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary="/Applications/Tor Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox")
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    time.sleep(3)
finally:
    driver.close()
```

I am trying to use Tor browser for scraping and everything works fine, but every time I run code you have to manually click connect button. How do I disable the confirmation screen or automatic its acceptance from within selenium? [image: Tor browser]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [tor](/questions/tagged/tor) browser configuration screen...

[image: connect_to_tor]

... comes up because you haven't configured *TOR Browser* [proxy](/questions/tagged/proxy) settings explicitly in your code block. So every time you execute your program, it initiates a new *TOR* browsing context without the proxy settings and assumes that you are running *Tor Browser* for the first time. Hence you will see the *Tor Network Settings* window on each run.

---

### Solution

To get rid of the *Tor Network Settings* window, you need to configure the *Tor Network Settings* in your code block as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
  import os

  torexe = os.popen(r'C:\Users\Soma Bhattacharjee\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe')
  profile = FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\Soma Bhattacharjee\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default')
  profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
  profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
  profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
  profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
  profile.update_preferences()
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile= profile, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://check.torproject.org")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: TOR_BROWSER]

---

### References

You can find a couple of detailed discussions in:

- [How to connect to Tor browser using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942553/how-to-connect-to-tor-browser-using-python/53942783#53942783)
- [How to use Tor with Chrome browser through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55689701/how-to-use-tor-with-chrome-browser-through-selenium/55702188#55702188)
- [Python - Tor Browser through Firefox, unable to click button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503036/python-tor-browser-through-firefox-unable-to-click-button/59506515#59506515)